# Casting structure pointer to union pointer

Tags: c, struct, casting, undefined-behavior, unions

I have a `union` containing various compatible `struct` members:

```
enum Type { T1, T2, … };

struct S1 { enum Type type; … };
struct S2 { enum Type type; … };
…

union U {
    enum Type type;
    struct S1 as_s1;
    struct S2 as_s2;
    …
};
```

The `type` field of these structures is treated as immutable, and only the field of the union corresponding to the current `type` is accessed. I am aware that casting `union U *` to `struct S1 *` is defined as long as the `type` invariant is upheld, but is the reverse also true?

```
struct S1 *s1 = malloc (sizeof (struct S1));
union U *u = (union U *)s1;
```

That is, is it safe to allocate only `sizeof (struct S1)` bytes and cast the result to `union U *`? I would like to avoid allocating `sizeof (union U)` bytes, which in my case may be significantly larger.

Comment: why have the `type` member of the union? Put type in a wrapping object generic wrapper to implement polymorphism.

Comment: @self: This is C, not C++. Just a standard tagged union.

Comment: That's right. You don't need C++ to do what I've described in my comment. Casting it to union is fine because the sizeof(your_union) is to be the max size of all members of the union. You can only access one member of the union at a time

Comment: @self: I know I can cast the value, I’m just wondering if the pointer cast is also defined, because the union could be more strictly aligned, and it seems strange to allow a `union U *` that can’t actually be dereferenced as such—in the above example, `*u` would surely be illegal.

Comment: @self: I’m assuming you meant `struct Wrapper { enum Type type; union { struct S1 as_s1; … } data; };`? That has the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The casts themselves are not likely to be a problem.  They are permitted as long as the struct and union types have the same alignment requirement.  Moreover, in that case the standard demands that if the value is converted back to the original type then the result shall compare equal to the original pointer, so no data is lost.

The problem is what happens when you *access* the pointed-to object as if it were a `union U`.  It is likely that some things you could do that way would work out fine, but others are definitely unsafe.  Specifically, you ask

> That is, is it safe to allocate only sizeof (struct S1) bytes and cast the result to union U *?

No, it is not safe.  The standard specifies:

> When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values. [...]
>
> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

(C2011, 6.2.6/6-7)

If you trigger one of those provisions, especially the latter, and the allocated space is not as big as the union's representation, then the program exhibits undefined behavior.  It is possible that you could avoid program actions that do so, but creating such extra constraints on program behavior cannot be characterized as "safe" in my book.

> I would like to avoid allocating sizeof (union U) bytes, which in my case may be significantly larger.

Since you apparently intend to use the `type` member of the union to identify which member to use, how about doing this:

```
struct generic_s {
    enum Type type;
    void *contents;
};

struct generic_s s = { T1 };
s.contents = malloc(sizeof (struct S1));
```

Pass around objects of type `struct_generic` directly to avoid extra allocations and deallocations:

```
do_something(s);  // i.e. not do_something(&s)
```

You would need to cast the `contents` pointer to dereference it, of course.  On the other hand, that's all just a bit of fancy wrapping around the pointer to identify the pointed-to type.  You could instead do without the wrapping and pass around the type information explicitly.