# casting structure pointer to union pointer in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I have a Union containing various struct member.

```
union U {
    struct S1 as_s1;
    struct S2 as_s2;
    …
};
```

How can I cast pointer to struct as_s1 to a pointer to union U in C++?

I know because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949501/casting-structure-pointer-to-union-pointer?rq=1) that it can be easily done using C casting. But I want to use the feature of Advance class type casting of C++ without causing any errors.

Comment: Except if you know exactly what your doing, especially if you know what _layout-compatible_ means, you **should not** make that cast.

Comment: The linked question tells you that this isn't safe even in C.

Comment: According to the answer you quote, even in C this is not permitted.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @interjay Shouldn't the cast be OK (assuming the same alignment requirements) as long as he casts the pointers back to the correct type before accessing the data pointed? Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: @AriHietanen That may or may not be valid, depending on alignment requirements of the struct and union. But even if it's valid, why would you want to cast if you can't access the pointer without casting back?

Comment: @Sourav, What's the real problem here? Are you wanting to be able to convert an S1 to an S2, and possible vice-versa?

Comment: Why not create U as a virtual base for S1 and S2 and then use dynamic_cast, which would be safe?

Answer (score 1):

From the standard 6.9.2.4.

> Two objects a and b are **pointer-interconvertible** if:
>
> 1. they are the same object, or
> 2. **one is a standard-layout union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object (12.3),**
> 3. one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, the first base class subobject of that object (12.2), or
> 4. there exists an object c such that a and c are pointer-interconvertible, and c and b are pointer-interconvertible.
>
> **If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a reinterpret_cast (8.2.10).**

This means that you can  convert them to each other using `reinterpret_cast`. However, you cannot access the memory of wrong type. E.g., following is a well-defined code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S1 {
  int i;
};

struct S2 {
  short int i;
};

union U {
  struct S1 as_s1;
  struct S2 as_s2;
};

void printUnion(U* u, int type) {
  if (type == 0){
    S1 *s1 = reinterpret_cast<S1*>(u);
    std::cout << s1->i << std::endl;
  } else {
    S2 *s2 = reinterpret_cast<S2*>(u);
    std::cout << s2->i << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  S1 s1{1};
  printData(reinterpret_cast<U*>(&s1), 0);
  S2 s2{2};
  printData(reinterpret_cast<U*>(&s2), 1);
}
```

But, if you give a wrong type parameter to the `printData`-function, the behavior is undefined.

In c++ it is hard to imagine a program with a good design where the cast would be needed. In c if you already have a need for a union object there might be a case where this could be used to implement polymorphism (of course no reinterpret_cast there). Though it is usually done with `void*`.

Answer (score -3):

The proper casting for such pointer casts is reinterpret_cast:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S1 {
  int x,y;
};

struct S2 {
  double a,b;
};

union U {
  struct S1 as_s1;
  struct S2 as_s2;
};

int main() {

  struct S1 mys1;

  union U *uptr  = reinterpret_cast<union U*>(&mys1);
  uptr->as_s1.x = 42;
  printf("%d\n",mys1.x);

  return 0;
}
```

Beware that since `sizeof(struct S1) < sizeof(struct S2)`, in this example, and you only allocated enough memory for the size of `S1`, if you try to do anything on `uptr->as_s1.b` you will corrupt the stack.

Comment: That's just *undefined behavior*, there's nothing "proper" about this

Comment: He asked how to perform the pointer cast without generating compile-time errors, and reinterpret_cast does exactly that.

Comment: @FBergo I know that I was looking for a solution but when I said "without causing any error", I meant that I didn't want any undesirable behaviour later in the code.

Comment: @FBergo there's no need to cast, there is no compile time error when using the `union` "C style" - but it's *undefined behavior* according to the standard

Comment: No this is not correct. You've just built a UB server.